# Как провести регрессию с помощью statsmodel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

Я пытаюсь сделать регрессию для каждой группы, "Branche" фрейма данных с помощью `statsmodels`. Однако каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь это сделать, возвращается nan. Например, со следующим кадром данных:

```
stock_2020  stock_2021  Branche
1203789   1369878       4222
1203789   1369878       4222
1193338                 1812
378726                  1812
88297                   1812
88297                   1812
4287508                 1812
4287508                 1812
4287508                 1812
724774  642650          1812
2947152 3219622         1812
352024  405613          1812
352024  405613          1812
889909  861088          1812
889909  861088          1812
119853                  1812
764503                  1812
1028966                 1812
709700  799389          1812
85619   231060          1812
23058   52859           1812
421565  443918          1812
1443123 1019643         1812
188508  374393          1812
121220  120100          1812
547485                  1812
42823                   1812
431497  819528          1812
2538255 3180496 1812
210115  251683  1812
5453689     1812
5453689     1812
5453689     1812
5453689     1812
89459059    78192209    1812
721692      1812
205752      1812
17968773                4531
17968773                4531
```

Учреждены энтонсы:

```
for branche in df_to_predict.Branche.dropna().unique():
    X = df_to_predict.loc[df_to_predict['Branche'] == branche]['stock_2020']
    y = df_to_predict.loc[df_to_predict['Branche'] == branche]['stock_2021']
    if y.isnull().values.any():
        print(branche, X.shape)
        X = sm.add_constant(X)
        model01 = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
        y_pred = model01.predict(X)
        print(y_pred)
        break
```

Но это возвращается ко мне:

```
1812.0 (35,)
146     NaN
254     NaN
1641    NaN
...
```

Я также попытался сделать это со всеми данными, но возвращается то же самое. Итак: как сделать регрессию с помощью statsmodel на dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Я предположил (и проверка показала, что это так и есть), что результат в виде всех `NA` возвращается в том случае, если в целевой переменной `y` есть `NA`.
Вам нужно исключить из данных строки, в которых выполняется условие `y.isnull()` и тогда регрессия заработает. Например, можно попробовать сделать так:

```
    condition = (df_to_predict['Branche'] == branche) &
                (~df_to_predict['stock_2021'].isnull())
    X = df_to_predict.loc[condition]['stock_2020']
    y = df_to_predict.loc[condition]['stock_2021']
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Но тогда как я могу предсказать иксы в нужном branche, для которого у меня нет у?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica Эээ, что-то я не пойму. Ну то есть мне кажется в целом я примерно понимаю что за задачу вы пытаетесь решить, но конкретно этот вопрос не понимаю. Вам нужно как-то чётче определиться какую задачу вы хотите решить и привести больше примеров в вопросе, чтобы стало понятнее.